# Is there a better way to manage Text Messages?

Tags: ios, messages, sms, iphone

Looking at the space distribution of my phone, I see that Messages account for 7 GB.

There are a lot of photos and videos that have been sent over the years and I am assuming that locating and deleting them would free up some space.

However, scrolling to the top and tapping `Load Earlier Messages` is really tedious, not to mention that it becomes ridiculously slow after the 20th tap or so.

Is there a better way to deal with getting rid of some text messages?

Answer (score 1):

If you are jailbroken, you can use [**iCleaner**](http://apt.thebigboss.org/onepackage.php?bundleid=org.altervista.exilecom.icleaner):

[image]

<sup>Source: http://www.iclarified.com/images/news/37323/160771/160771.jpg</sup>

> **Message attachments:** it deletes files sent and received via iMessage or MMS. The “smart” setting only deletes files that do not show up in any message, while “on” deletes all attachments (messages with attachments will show a blank icon).

<sup>Source: http://www.funkyspacemonkey.com/icleaner-ultimate-ios-device-cleaning-app</sup>